# MySQL Syntax Error - but I can't find it

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO mo_received 
(appid, msg, to, from, operator, keyword, smsid, udh, response, created) 
VALUES 
('13846', 'HELLO', '123456789', '987654321', 
'SKTELECOM', 'Cheese', 'MESSAGE', 'UDHSTUFF', '', NOW());
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'to, from, operator, keyword, smsid, udh, response, created)
>   VALUES ('13846', 'HE' at line 1

That's the error I get.

Strange thing is that if I remove the "to" and "from" fields and values the insert works ok.  But I don't see anything wrong with those fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think to and from are reserved keywords in my sql, use backticks:
(appid, msg, `to`, `from`, operator, keyword, smsid, udh, response, created)

Comment: Suggest you change the name of the field "from" it's a reserved word in SQL.  It's just going to cause you trouble. I'd call it "msgfrom" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

"to" and "from" are not recommended for column name. It's reserved.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

If you use reserved column name, surround with reverse single quote.

```
INSERT INTO mo_received (appid, msg, `to`, `from`, operator, keyword, smsid, udh, response, created)
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html